# Unable top execute delphi fireDAC Application on remote PC

Tags: delphi, informix, delphi-xe5, firedac

I have created an application in Delphi XE5 using Informix as DB and fireDAC as data access method. Now I want to install this application on some other remote PC. What are per-requisites for that. I mean what remote PC should have before I start installing the application. I tried to create a set up I executed it on remote PC. After installation, I executed the application, I get this error:

```
Exception ETDBXNativeException in module FireDAC.exe at 0025416A.

[FireDAC][Phys][TDBX][Informix] Unable to load dbxinf.dll (ErrorCode 193).  It 
may   be     missing from the system path.
```

Please help. Also guide is there another proper way to create set up for delphi applications

Comment: There's an entire section in the documentation regarding [Deploying FireDAC Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Deploying_%28FireDAC%29). Have you read it at all?

Comment: I have gone through that. But when I use deployment manager, It asks me to connect to remote machine. However I dnt have the PA Server and looking for some .NET like set up solution.

Comment: The documentation I referred you to has nothing to do with the Deployment Manager. It has specific information about the files you need to include in your deployment for FireDAC. *Read the topic I linked*.

Comment: I have gone through that Ken, Added the required files in deployment pane. Now what is the next step?

Comment: I have followed the steps there. But when I hit deploy button it asks for connection profile. I installed the PA Server. but when I set the properties(HostName, port etc) it says connection refused.

Comment: With FireDAC I would recommend to use Informix ODBC driver and FireDAC ODBC Bridge Driver. This combination is already more or less but well tested.